# How to expose utility functions within the Azure Portal

Tags: utility, azureportal

I would like to add some operational utility functions to my 100% Azure hosted application together with the ability to manually launch these utilities at arbitrary times in the day via the Azure Portal.

My current Azure technology stack is comprised of Web(Api)Apps, Function Apps, CosmosDb + DocumentDbApi and Azure Storage Queues. The application does not have an HTML front end.

An example of a utility function would be to reset demo tenant data in CosmosDb. One benefit of using the portal UI is that I would not have to authenticate invocation of my utility functions from a remote source.

I code exclusively in C# and to date scripting languages have been a personal no-go zone.

My current thinking is that I should create a "utilities" Function-App and then launch a function when required via the portal function-test feature. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

I created a function app via the Azure Portal and a new function to invoke my utility code. Within the Azure Portal under the C# template options for a new function, there is "Manual" option described as follows "A C# function that is triggered manually via the portal "Run" button".

In the absence of extra official Microsoft documentation I assume this is an isolated function hosted within a function App with no external bindings such as a Storage Queue. This provides a solution to my question as I hope there is no alternative invokable public URL endpoint linked to such a manual function.